# My persistence.xml is misunderstood

Tags: jpa, persistence

let's us begin directly by file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bd_antic" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/defacement_datasource</jta-data-source>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

here is my project structure :

project

src

```
--bean
         --ejbEntity
              ... My Entity EJB for persistence.xml
         --ejbSession
              ... My Ejb Session
```

And My persitence.xml is the one I gave above.

It should work because

1. I create my BoneCP connection with asadmin et I ping it in http://localhost:8080/
2. I put `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>`. So I don't need to inform specific classes by `<class></class>`

But I have the exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: bean.ejbEntity.Page@1d4f941 is not a known entity type.
```

I need help. So please.

Comment: exclude-unlisted-classes is optional outside of containers, so more information is needed - how have you packaged it, how are you obtaining the EntityManager and what provider?  Does it work if you explicitly list your entity?

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly list your entity? Sometimes(I'm serious). how are you obtaining the EntityManager and what provider? by **EntityManagerFactory**. how have you packaged it ? as above : bean.ejbEntity for Entity EJB.

Comment: I insist on the fact that **the execution doesn't work all the time**. The first time I run the server, generally it works. But after, I have the exception, until I restart the server. Detail : **Glassfish4.1**

Comment: Nobody already have this problem ? **Glassfish doesn't more than one time after takeoff ?** Some incoherence with persistence.xml ?

Comment: You have not defined the problem.  "But after".. after what?  You get an EntityManager from a factory, but did not state how you obtain the factory - is it injected and container managed or are you obtaining it and managing its lifecycle directly?  Since you don't state anything, my guess is that you are obtaining the factory from the Persistence class but not closing it when done with it.  This keeps it around, so if anything with your classloader changes, (like redeployment) the old one might be used underneath.

Comment: @Chris, I think **you are right**. I use Persistence class. I don't close it when I finish.  So the redeployment is erroneous. I will test to close it. Sometimes, my console detects  **unclosed connections**. I think it is due to the same cause. thanks